# Differential backup on the cloud for a list of files and folders on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, dropbox

Is there a tool that I can use on Linux to make a backup on the cloud for a list of files and folders so that only changes made to each individual file is uploaded to the cloud, without having to store duplicates locally. I think DropBox have something like that bu just for one folder, so I think I would need to have duplicates of each single file and folder in the list in the DropBox folder, and keep then in sync, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Duply](https://duply.net) (simple [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org)) for my Linux server backups because:

- it is incremental
- the backup is encrypted
- it is simpler than Duplicity

As mentioned [here](https://devarcs.com/blog/shell/linux/backup/duply-with-dropbox/), it can be configured on Ubuntu to backup to DropBox (I never tried myself).

Here is a list of protocols mentioned as theoretically supported on the duplicity page:

- Amazon S3
- Backblaze B2
- DropBox
- ftp
- GIO
- Google Docs
- Google Drive
- HSI
- Hubic
- IMAP
- local filesystem
- Mega.co
- Microsoft Azure
- Microsoft Onedrive
- par2
- Rackspace Cloudfiles
- rclone
- rsync
- Skylabel
- ssh/scp
- SwiftStack
- Tahoe-LAFS
- WebDAV

Also, I give Duply the list of folders to backup without ever having to duplicate those folders.

Finally, I never tried to backup a single file but [this page](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Backup_on_Linux_with_duply) mentions that single files can be configured to be backed up with Duply:

> Duply normally uses a whitelist. To include certain directories or files from a backup the exclude file must be created in the Duply directory. The syntax allows you to add directories and **files** using + /pfad/zur/datei. To exclude a directory the exclude ein - /pfad/zum/Verzeichnis command must be inserted. In addition, Duply allows the use of wild cards. The file illustrated here exclude secures the directory /etc/, /root/, /var/www/ and excludes all other directories.
>
> - /etc/
> - /root/
> - /var/www/
>
> - **